# An Issue with saving SalesOrders data from REST API call to Exact Online

Tags: exact-online, picqer-exact-php-client

I have been using [PHP Client library for Exact Online](https://github.com/picqer/exact-php-client) for a long time.

After saving the customer Accounts, Addresses, Contacts and then filtering out the PaymentConditions based on WooCommerce orders, items are successfully reflecting in the Exact Online dashboard.

But unfortunately calling the [SalesOrders](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=SalesOrderSalesOrders) post request API. I'm unable to store into the Exact Online dashboard, 
even though in order to store only `OrderedBy` itself is enough which is given in the official documentation

> ```
> $ordersn = $order->save();
> ```
>
> > Picqer\Financials\Exact\ApiException : Error 403: Forbidden

```
$order = new SalesOrder($connection);
$lines = new SalesOrderLine($connection);


....

echo'<pre>'; print_r($order); 
$order->SalesOrderLines = $lines;
$ordersn = $order->save();
if ($ordersn->ID)
{
    $orderitem['sync_flag'] = true;
}
```

Here is the details of an order array

```
Picqer\Financials\Exact\SalesOrder Object
(
    ...
    [attributes:protected] => Array
            (
                [WarehouseID] => 26ca2016-453f-499a-8a34-c986009bc78d
                [OrderID] => FC290B7D-766B-4CBB-B7A2-47327AA3841F
                [OrderedBy] => 764a4f6d-4b39-43b4-a86c-265e5478afbd
                [DeliverTo] => 764a4f6d-4b39-43b4-a86c-265e5478afbd
                [OrderDate] => 2019-02-17T19:29:53
                [YourRef] => 75591901YP220320G
                [OrderedByName] => Peter Kerner
                [Description] => 16031_PayPal/Lastschrift/Kreditkarte
                [Remarks] => Order is processing
                [PaymentReference] => 16031
                [PaymentCondition] => 
                [SalesOrderLines] => Picqer\Financials\Exact\SalesOrderLine Object
                    (
                        [attributes:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [OrderID] => FC290B7D-766B-4CBB-B7A2-47327AA3841F
                                [VATAmount] => 5,58
                                [Description] => Goodies Box
                                [Quantity] => 1,00
                                [UnitPrice] => 29,37
                                [Item] => 418d43d6-55fe-410a-8df2-b05cbb72cea5
                            )
                            ...
                    )
            )
    ...
)
```

Do we need to upload **VAT code** or Am I missing something else data to be resided first shown from the above order-array or what else should we need to call appropriate API. Since in-order to reflect on the Exact Online dashboard. what should we need to follow?

From the built-In function call `addItem()` below snippets of code:

```
$soLines = array(
                'OrderID' => $lines->OrderID,
                'Item' => $lines->Item,
                'Description' =>  $lines->Description,
                'Quantity' => $lines->Quantity,
                'UnitPrice' => $lines->UnitPrice,
                'VATAmount' => $lines->VATAmount,
                'VATCode' => $lines->VATCode
           );
$order->addItem($soLines);
```

**Generates the results with `LineNumber` to be included in `SalesOrderLines` array**

```
[attributes:protected] => Array
(
    [WarehouseID] => 26ca2016-453f-499a-8a34-c986009bc78d
    [OrderID] => 65F93F56-97A8-4D54-AE37-C0BDDE774E67
    [OrderedBy] => 9b048b81-f729-413a-b196-526436f11fe7
    [DeliverTo] => 9b048b81-f729-413a-b196-526436f11fe7
    [OrderDate] => 2019-02-17T20:45:34
    [YourRef] => 9Y9593859V795183K
    [OrderedByName] => Katrin Lenk
    [Description] => 16033_PayPal Express
    [Remarks] =>  Order is processing
    [PaymentReference] => 16033
    [PaymentCondition] => 
    [SalesOrderLines] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [OrderID] => 65F93F56-97A8-4D54-AE37-C0BDDE774E67
                    [Item] => 5c415369-615c-4953-b28c-c7688f61cfaa
                    [Description] => ABC Classic
                    [Quantity] => 2,00
                    [UnitPrice] => 15,08
                    [VATAmount] => 5,73
                    [VATCode] => 
                    [LineNumber] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Also note I haven't created Journals, GLAccounts, Documents & DocumentAttachments API. Does this actually affects storing of SalesOrders

---

**EDIT:**

In much simpler

```
$salesOrder = new \Picqer\Financials\Exact\SalesOrder($connection);
$salesOrder->WarehouseID = '26ca2016-453f-499a-8a34-c986009bc78d';
$salesOrder->OrderID = '65F93F56-97A8-4D54-AE37-C0BDDE774E67';
$salesOrder->OrderedBy = '9b048b81-f729-413a-b196-526436f11fe7';
$salesOrder->DeliverTo = '9b048b81-f729-413a-b196-526436f11fe7';
$salesOrder->OrderDate = '2019-02-17T20:45:34';
$salesOrder->YourRef = '9Y9593859V795183K';
$salesOrder->OrderedByName = 'Katrin Lenk';
$salesOrder->Description = '16033_PayPal Express';
$salesOrder->Remarks = 'Order is processing';
$salesOrder->PaymentReference = '16033';
$salesOrder->PaymentCondition = 'PP';

$soLines = array(
    'Item' => '5c415369-615c-4953-b28c-c7688f61cfaa',
    'Description' => 'ABC Classic',
    'Quantity' => '1,00',
    'UnitPrice' => '29,37',
    'OrderID' => '65F93F56-97A8-4D54-AE37-C0BDDE774E67'
);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($soLines);
$salesOrder->addItem($soLines);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($salesOrder);
$salesOrder->save();
```

**Resulting value stored from the `soLines` array**

```
[attributes:protected] => Array
(
    [WarehouseID] => 26ca2016-453f-499a-8a34-c986009bc78d
    [OrderID] => 65F93F56-97A8-4D54-AE37-C0BDDE774E67
    [OrderedBy] => 9b048b81-f729-413a-b196-526436f11fe7
    [DeliverTo] => 9b048b81-f729-413a-b196-526436f11fe7
    [OrderDate] => 2019-02-17T20:45:34
    [YourRef] => 9Y9593859V795183K
    [OrderedByName] => Katrin Lenk
    [Description] => 16033_PayPal Express
    [Remarks] =>  Order is processing
    [PaymentReference] => 16033
    [PaymentCondition] => 
    [SalesOrderLines] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [OrderID] => 65F93F56-97A8-4D54-AE37-C0BDDE774E67
                    [Item] => 5c415369-615c-4953-b28c-c7688f61cfaa
                    [Description] => ABC Classic
                    [Quantity] => 2,00
                    [UnitPrice] => 15,08
                    [VATAmount] => 5,73
                    [VATCode] => 
                    [LineNumber] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

**Actual Result:**

> Picqer\Financials\Exact\ApiException : Error 403: Forbidden

Answer (score 0):

The reason was `OrderID` value was included twice in the `SalesOrderLine` as well as in `SalesOrder` for the two REST API calls and removing the `OrderID` entry from `SalesOrder` worked perfectly and reflecting in the Exact Online Dashboard

You cannot assign `$order->SalesOrderLines = $lines;` directly resulting in a collection to array error. 
The only way to do this was to call via in-built function called `addItem()` passing array objects into it.